# how do you subset data dict based on values in array in python

Tags: python

I have this data dictionary:

```
slots={'ibm':5, 'chev': 9, 'exx':10}
```

I need to be able to subset this slots dict based on values in array mod:

```
mod=['ibm', 'exx']
```

I tried this

```
dict((i, slots)[i] for i in mod if i in slots)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices not str
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Using a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-dictionary-comprehension):

```
>>> slots = {'ibm':5, 'chev': 9, 'exx':10}
>>> mod = ['ibm', 'exx']
>>> {k: slots[k] for k in mod}
{'ibm': 5, 'exx': 10}
```

Comment: and if `slots` does not contain some of the `mod` keys?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest  either `slots.get(k, default)` or adding `if k in slots` to the comprehension, depends what you want to happen in that case..

Answer (score 1):

You should get values from `slots` dictionary. I guess you want to pick from dict based on keys:

`dict((i, slots[i]) for i in mod if i in slots)`

To avoid `KeyError`, you can filter as following:

`dict((i, slots[i]) for i in slots if i in mod)`